# jQuery - merging ajax requests as have them split up and replacing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im new to js/ jquery so think ive done ok to get this far however ive noticed an issue with my code and think i need to somehow merge it together.

If i enter email, it updates in database, however as soon as i do firstname or lastname it updates those but then removes the email...

here is the JS so far:

```
// function to check email field, validate and save to ac for this customer session
function checkIt(field) {
    field = $(field);
    var email = field.val();
    var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
    var emailInputId = field.attr('id');
    if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length > 0) {
        $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
    }
    //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
    if (validEmail(email)) {
        //alert('valid email');
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': email
            },
            caching: true
        });
        field.removeClass('cm-failed-field');
        field.prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
        field.next("span").remove();
    } else {
        field.addClass('cm-failed-field');
        field.prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
        field.after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
    }
}

// lets check if the email input was already populated, such as browser auto fill etc.. if so use that and save
var field = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];
if ($(field).length > 0) {
    if (field.value) {
        checkIt(field);
    }
}

// check email thats inputted and save to ac session for this customer, or if email changed to update
$('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {
    checkIt(this);
});

// if first name entered lets grab it and add to the ac session for the customer
var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';

$(firstname_sel+','+lastname_sel).blur(function() {
    var firstname = $(firstname_sel).val();
    var lastname = $(lastname_sel).val();
    $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'firstname': firstname,
            'lastname': lastname
        },
        caching: true
    });
});

// lets grab the first name and last name if already in input
var firstname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input')[0];
var lastname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input')[0];
if ($(firstname_sel_pre).length > 0 || $(lastname_sel_pre).length > 0) {
    if (firstname_sel_pre.value || lastname_sel_pre.value) {
        var firstname_pre = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
        var lastname_pre = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'firstname': firstname_pre,
                'lastname': lastname_pre
            },
            caching: true
        });
    }
}
```

PHP

```
if ($mode == 'email') {
//die('post was recieved from js to this controller! yippie!!');
//print_r($_POST['email']);
//die($_POST['email']);

/**************Start: Abandoned Carts *********************/
$_SESSION['cart']['user_data']['email'] = $_POST['email'];

$cartContents=mysql_escape_string(serialize($_SESSION['cart']['products']));
$shippingCost=$_SESSION['cart']['shipping_cost'];
$tax=$_SESSION['cart']['tax_summary']['total'];
$orderTotal=$_SESSION['cart']['total'];
$userFirstName=$_POST['firstname'];
$userLastName=$_POST['lastname'];
$userEmail=$_POST['email'];
$userId=$_SESSION['settings']['cu_id']['value'];
$userExpiry=$_SESSION['settings']['cu_id']['expiry'];
$date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$userExist=db_get_fields("SELECT user_id FROM cscart_abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = '".$userId."'");
if($userExist) {
    db_query("UPDATE cscart_abandoned_cart SET first_name='".$userFirstName."', last_name='".$userLastName."', email='".$userEmail."', shipping='".$shippingCost."',tax='".$tax."',order_total='".$orderTotal."',cart='".$cartContents."',last_updated='".$date."',status='0' WHERE user_id='".$userId."'");
} else {
    db_query("INSERT INTO cscart_abandoned_cart (first_name,last_name,email,cart,user_id,expiry,last_updated,shipping,tax,order_total,status)values('".$userFirstName."','".$userLastName."','".$userEmail."','".$cartContents."','".$userId."','".$userExpiry."','".$date."','".$shippingCost."','".$tax."','".$orderTotal."','0')");
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have had a read about setting global vars but got as far as i can and a little stuck, i put the ajax request in a new function (not sure if that was right) or if i done correctly but a little lost now on how i should call the ajax function?

```
// set global variables
var checkoutEmail = "";
var checkoutFirstName = "";
var checkoutLastName = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    function fireCheckoutAC(checkoutEmail, checkoutFirstName, checkoutLastName) {
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': checkoutEmail,
                'firstname': checkoutFirstName,
                'lastname': checkoutLastName
            },
            caching: true
        });
    }
    // function to check email field, validate and save to ac for this customer session
    function checkIt(field) {
        field = $(field);
        var email = field.val();
        var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
        var emailInputId = field.attr('id');
        if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length > 0) {
            $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
        }
        //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
        if (validEmail(email)) {
            //alert('valid email');
            checkoutEmail = email;
            field.removeClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.next("span").remove();
        } else {
            field.addClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
        }
    }

    // lets check if the email input was already populated, such as browser auto fill etc.. if so use that and save
    var field = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];
    if ($(field).length > 0) {
        if (field.value) {
            checkIt(field);
        }
    }

    // check email thats inputted and save to ac session for this customer, or if email changed to update
    $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {
        checkIt(this);
    });

    // if first name entered lets grab it and add to the ac session for the customer
    var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
    var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';

    $(firstname_sel+','+lastname_sel).blur(function() {
        checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel).val();
        checkoutLastName = $(lastname_sel).val();
    });

    // lets grab the first name and last name if already in input
    var firstname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input')[0];
    var lastname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input')[0];
    if ($(firstname_sel_pre).length > 0 || $(lastname_sel_pre).length > 0) {
        if (firstname_sel_pre.value || lastname_sel_pre.value) {
            checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
            checkoutLastName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Been thinking about it, i guess we need to just do 1 ajax request but pass email, firstname and lastname as global variables? thats my logic anyway but not sure how to do that. Hoping someone could help as need to finish for release tomorrow and 2:20am now haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the solution, here it is:

```
/* grab completed email when enetred into checkout and add to abandoned cart for that session */
function validEmail(v) {
    var r = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return (v.match(r) == null) ? false : true;
}

// set global variables
var checkoutEmail = "";
var checkoutFirstName = "";
var checkoutLastName = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    function fireCheckoutAC() {
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': checkoutEmail,
                'firstname': checkoutFirstName,
                'lastname': checkoutLastName
            },
            caching: true
        });
    }
    // function to check email field, validate and save to ac for this customer session
    function checkIt(field) {
        field = $(field);
        var email = field.val();
        var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
        var emailInputId = field.attr('id');
        if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length > 0) {
            $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
        }
        //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
        if (validEmail(email)) {
            //alert('valid email');
            checkoutEmail = email;
            fireCheckoutAC();
            field.removeClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.next("span").remove();
        } else {
            field.addClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
        }
    }

    // lets check if the email input was already populated, such as browser auto fill etc.. if so use that and save
    var field = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];
    if ($(field).length > 0) {
        if (field.value) {
            checkIt(field);
        }
    }

    // check email thats inputted and save to ac session for this customer, or if email changed to update
    $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {
        checkIt(this);
    });

    // if first name entered lets grab it and add to the ac session for the customer
    var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
    var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';

    $(firstname_sel+','+lastname_sel).blur(function() {
        checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel).val();
        checkoutLastName = $(lastname_sel).val();
        fireCheckoutAC();
    });

    // lets grab the first name and last name if already in input
    var firstname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input')[0];
    var lastname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input')[0];
    if ($(firstname_sel_pre).length > 0 || $(lastname_sel_pre).length > 0) {
        if (firstname_sel_pre.value || lastname_sel_pre.value) {
            checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
            checkoutLastName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
            fireCheckoutAC();
        }
    }

});
```